# What is the difference between racha and turbonada?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Both articles exist on Wikipedia, but nowhere is it explained what the difference is.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Wikipedia is not the only source. You can search the RAE dictionary, wordreference, or simply google each word and easily find their definitions. Questions that show no effort are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

**Racha** - *Gust*
**Turbonada** - *Sustained gusts / wind storm*

**Racha** indicates a transient variation of the wind speed whereas **turbonada** refers to a sustained wind speed increase. Any variation in the wind speed worth of mentioning is called **racha** whereas a **turbonada** is a big variation in the wind speed that is sustained for a larger period of time. **Turbonada** in some parts is the same as **chubasco** meaning rain with strong winds,

**Racha** is commonly used in meteorological reports:

> Reporte metereológico: Temperatura 17 grados, presión 29.92, viento de 090 a 10 nudos con **rachas** de 15, completamente nublado, techo 3000 pies. Se esperan **chubascos** y tomentas eléctricas.

It means that the wind speed is 10 knots but there are variations in which the wind speed can increase up to 15 knots. I haven't seen **turbonada** on a weather report maybe it's because the term could be ambiguous or maybe I haven't seen enough reports.

---

**Racha** - *Spree / streak*

> — Hola amigo ¿Cómo te vá?
> — ¡Mal!. Traigo una mala **racha**: me corrieron del trabajo, mi novia me dejó y se acaba de descomponer mi carro.

Comment: I agree, _chubascos_ are what weather forecasts usually have.

Answer (score 0):

- A **racha** is just a gust of wind.
- A **turbonada** is a storm with rain, wind and also lightinings and thunders. It might contain gusts of wind.

According to the diccionary of the Real Academia Española de la Lengua (RAE):

> Turbonada
>
> turbonada De turbón.
>
> 1. f. Fuerte chubasco de viento y agua, acompañado de truenos, relámpagos y rayos.
>
> fuente: https://dle.rae.es/turbonada

> Racha
>
> Quizá del ár. ráǧǧa 'sacudida', 'agitación', 'tormenta'.
>
> 1. f. Ráfaga de aire.
> 2. f. En cualquier actividad, período breve de fortuna o desgracia.
>
> fuente: https://dle.rae.es/racha